# Validation rules occur error

Tags: java, regex, validation

Can someone help me check my validation rules since it shows the error illegal escape character..thanks..

```
if(staffICNo.length() == 0 || !staffICNo.matches("([0-9][0-9])((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))((0[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))\-([0-9][0-9])\-([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"IC Number must be in this format : 101010-10-1010..","",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Comment: Could you tag your question with the programming language your code snippet has been wrote in? Otherwise it'll be hard for the answerers to find your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some escape character problem. In java you need to escape the '\' charater inside a string.
Try

```
if(staffICNo.length() == 0 || !staffICNo.matches("([0-9][0-9])((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))((0[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))\\-([0-9][0-9])\\-([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"IC Number must be in this format : 101010-10-1010..","",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few `\-` sequences. They mean you're trying to escape the `-` at the string level, which is meaningless. Use `\\-` to escape it at the regular expression level (the compiler will then consider the first backslash as escaping the second, and the string passed to `showMessageDialog` will contain the wanted `\-` sequence).